# How to replace each stream data of a pdf file?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm working on a pdf decrypt task. My preferred library to parse/handle pdf is iText.

For example, below is one of the stream data from the encrypted pdf file. As you can see, it contains two filters: VendorPDFEncrypt and FlateDecode. VendorPDFEncrypt is provided by the pdf vendor and the corresponding decrypt method is provided as well.

```
6 0 obj
<</Length 608/Filter[/VendorPDFEncrypt/FlateDecode]>>stream
encryptedBy_FlateDecode_VendorPDFEncrypt_data
endstream
endobj
```

My target is to iterate each stream data, then decrypt it, remove the "VendorPDFEncrypt" string from Filter and recalculate the Length(e.g. 608 -> 598). The target stream data should be as below.

```
6 0 obj
<</Filter[/FlateDecode]/Length 598>>stream
encryptedBy_FlateDecode_data
endstream
endobj
```

And my code to do the work is as below. My questions are:

(1) How to get the total count of pdf objects?

(2) How to replace the stream data?

(3) How to remove "VendorPDFEncrypt" from the filter and recalculate the Length?

```
var pdf = new PdfReader(file);
int i = 0;

while (true)
{
    // TODO: need to find a better way to get the total count of pdf objects
    i++;
    if (i > 1000)
        break;

    PdfObject obj = pdf.GetPdfObject(i);

    if (obj != null && obj.IsStream())
    {
        PRStream encryptedStream = (PRStream)pdf.GetPdfObject(i);
        byte[] encryptedBytes = PdfReader.GetStreamBytesRaw(encryptedStream);
        byte[] decryptedContent = VendorDecrypt.__DecryptHelper(DecryptFileFormat.Buffer, key, random, encryptedBytes);

        // TODO: replace the original encrypted content with decryptedContent
        // decryptedContent = encryptedBy_FlateDecode_data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***(Q1) How to get the total count of pdf objects?***

A1) Under certain conditions, many PDFs can actually work without the total count, if say the file was not too severely truncated, however the object count in 9 out of 10 cases can be expected in the tail end of file:-

`trailer <</Size 15` indicates entry 14 0 obj  should be expected somewhere (in reality that would mean 16 or more) including header and trailer and any incremental or other generations

Even a password encrypted file should have a similar entry, unless its encrypted !

```
/Size 12 /Type /XRef /W [1 2 1] >>stream
xÚÁ±@ Á{Gf†*PŠL¤¥hF?ÈùvJicÑ!,È|"×©1±úý3ÏÑXÃúÊ´ñBMÖ
```

A 1.5) how to extract a stream easily, well if you know the object numbers and the object location is not encrypted then you can export them easily for adapt and return

Program Usage: `pdftosrc <PDF-file> [<stream-object-number>]`

If I request object 5 which looks something like

```
5 0 obj
<<
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 100
>>
stream
xœ3Ð375 =T†.¦œ…‰¡ž¥‘‰‰Br.W!¦¦\.#c > C„h²¨‰!œ™ƒ0E4ƒ+\K!h6ÃDÒƒÍ õ=sÓS
\ò¹¹¹ ,.8
endstream
```

### Response

```
0.750000 0.000000 0.000000 -0.750000 0.000000 841.920044 cm
q
0.000000 0.000000 m
230.720001 0.000000 l
230.720001 410.720001 l
0.000000 410.720001 l
h
W* n
q
230.720001 0.000000 0.000000 -410.720001 0.000000 410.720001 cm
/Image1 Do
Q
Q
```

***(Q2) How to replace the stream data?***

A2) The safest way when you have confidence is use a hex editor in DECIMAL address mode this avoids running the file and lets you measure, cut, paste, insert   and overwrite the 8 bit binary bytes. (and has search/replace obj flags, etc abilities)
[image]

There are also PDF COS analysers that allow to export streams here is an old one from Apryse (PDFtron/iText/Etc.) and their better known one is possibly RUPS

This file is password to open (which I dont Know) thus all raw data is encoded as encrypted.

[image]

***(Q3) How to remove "VendorPDFEncrypt" from the filter and recalculate the Length?***

A3) The editor has find and replace (=nothing) abilities, and for a small number of counts its easy to measure/repair the changes. But for more than a handful of entries you may want to decompress a file for bulk edits. However as your focus is vendor encryption that could be more difficult unless you know the password for the decompression.

Clearly seeing the requested minimal sample for an accurate answer, would help to determine best methodology.